# Check ufw default policy action

Tags: firewall, ufw

I know it's very easy to set the default behavior of ufw, e.g. `ufw default deny`, but how do I **check** what the default POLICY action is?  It does not show in `ufw status`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try `ufw status verbose`:

```
root@cmp:~# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
```

Now I change it to allow:

```
root@cmp:~# ufw default allow
Default incoming policy changed to 'allow'
(be sure to update your rules accordingly)
```

Status is reflected accordingly, the default has changed to allow:

```
root@cmp:~# ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: allow (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip
```